# Cypress: using either or with expect

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, cypress, chai

I am using cypress and have an object with some properties for example:

```js
const obj={
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3
}
```

I want to check there that this object:

1. either should not have property `myProp`
2. or should have property `myProp` as an empty string
3. or should have a property `myProp` as undefined

I tried firstly with the first two conditions but failed there itself, hence can't make it to all the 3 conditions.

This is what I tried:

```js
expect(obj)
        .either.not.to.have.a.property('myProp')
        .or.to.have.a.property('myProp')
        .that.is.a('string').and.is.empty;
```

And I get to see the error as:
[image]

Please help me:

1. to use either/or
2. to check all the 3 conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom matcher, a function that has any amount of complexity and returns true or false.

```js
function checkMyProp(obj) {
  const myProp = obj['myProp'];
  return myProp === undefined ||
    (myProp !== undefined && typeof myProp === 'string' && myProp === '');
}

it('succeeds when myProp does not exist', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3 }
  expect(obj).to.satisfy(checkMyProp, 'myProp meets the criteria');
})

it('succeeds when myProp is an empty string', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3, myProp: '' }
  expect(obj).to.satisfy(checkMyProp, 'myProp meets the criteria');
})

it('fails when myProp is a string but not empty', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3, myProp: 'myValue' }
  expect(obj).to.satisfy(checkMyProp, 'myProp meets the criteria');
})

it('fails when myProp is a number', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3, myProp: 4 }
  expect(obj).to.satisfy(checkMyProp, 'myProp meets the criteria');
})
```

---

If you want to configure the matcher in the test, use a higher order function (function that returns a function)

```js
function matcherFor(prop) {
  return (obj) => {
    const myProp = obj[prop];
    return myProp === undefined ||
      (myProp !== undefined && typeof myProp === 'string' && myProp === '');
  }
}

it('succeeds when myProp does not exist', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3 }
  expect(obj).to.satisfy(matcherFor('myProp'), 'myProp meets the criteria');
})
```

---

Or as a one-liner (typeof check is implicit in `===` operator)

```js
const matcherFor = (prop) => (obj) => obj[prop] === undefined || obj[prop] === '';
```

---

You can use the same syntax with a `.should()` as a validation step in a command

```js
it('as a validation step in a test chain', () => {
  const obj={ a:1, b:2, c:3 }
  cy.wrap(obj)
    .should('satisfy', matcherFor('myProp'), 'myProp meets the criteria')
    .then(obj => {
      // process object
    })
})
```